# UIImageView animation crashing (sigabrt)

Tags: ios

Any idea why this crashes? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
-(IBAction)animationOneStart { 

NSMutableArray* arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

for(int count = 1; count <= 22; count++)
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testDance3_%03d.jpg", count];
    UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img];
    [img release];
}

loadingImageView.animationImages = arrayOfImages;
[arrayOfImages release];

loadingImageView.animationDuration = 3;
loadingImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1; //Repeats indefinitely

[loadingImageView startAnimating];

loadingImageView.animationImages = nil;
[loadingImageView release];
}
```

Comment: What kind of an error are you getting? Where does loadingImageView come from?

Comment: I'm getting a "Program received signal: SIGABRT" on     [arrayOfImages addObject:img];

Comment: Well, you're initializing an array with capacity for 10 but then putting 22 objects in it... so I'd check that first.

Comment: Have you tried to add some NSLog statements in that loop?  Is it failing on the 21st iteration?  Is it failing straight out on the first add?

Comment: @isaac - the initWithCapacity is the initial capacity.  It's questionable why he inits with 10 when he knows he's going to add 21 but it shouldn't cause a problem - just less efficient.

Comment: @bryanmac Yeah, I wasn't sure about that, but thought it was odd that that the crash is a sigabrt when adding to the mutableArray. Good to know.

Comment: yeah, that was just a typo... could it be something with the UIImage alloc?

Comment: What happens when you add a ton of NSLog in that loop and step through it with a debugger?  Log out the path ... etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing your NSMutableDictionary with capacity for the same quantity of object's you'll be storing in it. If that doesn't work, I'd try to comment out these two lines:

```
//loadingImageView.animationImages = nil;
//[loadingImageView release];
```

In the scope of this code, your other calls appear balanced. But we can't see what's happening inside loadingImageView, and so my guess is that either the loadingImageView itself or it's animations are being released prematurely.

Comment: thanks, loadingImageView is just an UIImageView... IBOutlet UIImageView *loadingImageView;

Comment: Ok, in that case you probably are releasing both the animatingImages and that view itself prematurely. I *think* you could nil that animationImages in 'animationDidComplete', but you shouldn't be releasing that loadingImageView until you have either removed it from it's superView or in your viewDidUnload method.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see enough code confirm this, but a couple things that are suspicious are here:

```
[loadingImageView startAnimating];

loadingImageView.animationImages = nil;
[loadingImageView release];
```

So, while the animation is running, you are releasing the images that are being animated?  Or the view which, itself, is animating?  Probably one or the other or both is the problem.

If the animation is supposed to run indefinitely, you are going to need to keep the view around indefinitely.  And if it stops eventually, you should release it after it stops.

Comment: +1 - the animation goes on async - shouldn't release right after *starting* the animation.  I would comment out the releases and nils just to confirm and then consider releasing later ...

Comment: yeah, that's what i suggested 20 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You call to addObject will fail when nil is passed. The UIImage could be nil when your system run out of memory and cannot allocate more. When that happens depends on how large your images are, but basically you can be sure that sooner of later use of loadingImageView.animationImages combined with allocating all your UIImage objects at the same time will cause your app to crash. See also [playing-looping-images-sequence-in-uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330865/playing-looping-images-sequence-in-uiview/9332139#comment24880423_9332139). You basically need a different approach that does not hold all the images in memory at the same time, the uncompressed images consume way too much memory.